# Selenium with WebDriver - wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a Selenium test suite in Java, using WebDriver.
I have a generic wait function in place that takes a CSS selector and wait for the element to become present and visible before moving on to assertions, using WebDriverWait. Now, though, I want to have something that waits for all elements of a certain type, that are in the DOM to not be visible anymore, before proceeding. The exact example is that I have a number of images being loaded and I want to wait for their loading spinners to disappear before continuing. Haven't been able to find something that would solve this for me yet, so posting it here.
Any clues?

Thanks!

```
public void waitForPageToLoad(WebDriver webDriver, String cssToWaitFor) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(cssToWaitFor)));
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your current generic "waiting" method so we can adapt it.

Comment: Sure! Original post edited.

Comment: @Arran: What happened to your reputation? Someone was deleted?

Comment: @user1177636 Unfortunately yes :( Didn't really get a who or why from the mods but ultimately yes, someone who was deleted and their reputation went with them. Imagine my surprise when I logged in and found out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `invisibilityOfElementLocated` expected condition. [Reference](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29). From the doc:

> ```
> invisibilityOfElementLocated
>
> public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
>
> An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.
>
> Parameters:
>     locator - used to find the element
> ```

So you could use it like:

```
public void waitForInvisibility(WebDriver webDriver, String cssToWaitFor) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(cssToWaitFor)));
}
```

---

Alternatively you can look into `public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> not(ExpectedCondition<?> condition)`, which by the doc does:

> An expectation with the logical opposite condition of the given
>   condition.